# Which package produces these outputs?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, packages

Does anyone happen to know which package produces these types of symbols? In particular, you can tell the symbols for `\leq`, `\subseteq`, `\in`, etc. are somewhat smaller.

[image: Probability]

[image: Set Theory]

Comment: do you have that as a PDF?, if so you don't need to guess: the pdf font menu or pdffonts command line utility will tell you which fonts are being used

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the font is the standard LaTeX font (Computer Modern), but there is a specific math package that creates these symbol changes. It's not a matter of font.

Comment: it doesn't look at all like cm to me (the integral is a completely different shape, but you didn't answer the question, do you have the PDF?

Comment: As Sebastiano says, the document is using `MnSymbol`, but it's a bad choice, from a typographic point of view, because the symbols clash with the letters. Probably the author wanted to use some of the symbols provided by the package, but the result is very disputable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font is `Mnsymbol` package....after 15' of my search...and research.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,Mnsymbol}

\begin{document}
\[\mathbb{P}(X\leq a)\int_{-\infty}^a \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa Hi, if you remove amsfonts I have an error on \mathbb{P} that not exist for MnSymbol. You can do a compilation.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, in my mind I mixed `amsfonts` with `amssymb`. Time to go to bed...